# sending email sendgrid received in promotion tab not in primary

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

We are using sendgrid free tier for our nodejs application when we send a automated email the email received in promotion tab not in primary tab how we can solve this issue should we buy paid tier of sendgrid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can come from the text entered in the email. The google algorithm detects ads and social networks so it comes from the content of the email.

Comment: It's weird because i have made a mail that ended up in promotion but it's to send the user data to be GDPR compliant, not promotional at all neither is the text...