# Sendgrid mail in promotional tab Gmail instead of inbox

Tags: sendgrid

I have the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572119/sending-email-sendgrid-received-in-promotion-tab-not-in-primary).

However, after reaching out the SendGrid support they have no idea why it would be refused. I am using SendGrid to send to my customers their data when they request it to comply with GDPR.

So this is clearly not a promotional email, but I have an attachment (a `data.json` file).

Here is the email content:

> Hello,
>
> You have asked for your personal data on MY_APP_NAME, you will find them as attachment.
>
> Wishing you a very good day,
> The MY_APP_NAM team

Could you please tell what is wrong in the email so Gmail AI thinks it's promotional?

Comment: Very likely it is classified as promotional **because** you sent it through SendGrid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sending email sendgrid received in promotion tab not in primary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572119/sending-email-sendgrid-received-in-promotion-tab-not-in-primary)

Comment: oh alright if this comes from SendGrid itself... I have seen they justify that it's not their fault : https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260802576170-Avoiding-the-Gmail-Promotional-Tab. 
That's why i ask a question

Comment: It's the link i have provided in my question, so it doesn't answer it because it's apparently regarding my email content. But i definitely don't know what could be interpreted as promotion ?

Comment: SendGrid has no control over this. We don't know how GMail performs the classification, but I wouldn't be surprised it is because SendGrid is used a lot to send promotional emails, so other emails originating from SendGrid servers will also be classified as promotional.

Comment: okay then let's close this question and i will try to find another solution my emails from my Cloud Functions.

Comment: I voted to close as duplicate, because you are asking the exact same question. In any case, you don't actually seemed to have followed the recommendations from SendGrid on the link in your comment (for example, it doesn't have a personalised greeting, and the quality of your content is also pretty low).

Comment: Thanks i will try to add some personalised greeting and see how it goes first.